# Showing that $d_1(x,y) := |x - y|$ and $d_2(x,y) := \left| \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right|$ induce same topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $M := [1,\infty)$ and define $$d_1(x,y) := |x - y| \qquad
> \text{and} \qquad d_2(x,y) := \left| \frac{1}{x} -
> \frac{1}{y}\right|.$$ Show that $d_1$ and $d_2$ induce the same
>   topology on $M$.

As far as I can see, there are two possibilities of showing this: We show either, that the two metrics are strongly equivalent, i.e. that $$c_1 d_1(x,y) \leq d_2(x,y) \leq c_2d_1(x,y)$$ holds for all $x,y \in M$ and $c_1,c_2 > 0$ or we use an exercise in the book by Lee (Topological manifolds, p.22):

> $d_1$ and $d_2$ induce same topology $\Leftrightarrow$ For all $x \in
> M$, $r > 0$ there exist $r_1,r_2 > 0$ such that $$B_{r_1}^{(d_1)}(x)
> \subseteq B_{r}^{(d_2)}(x) \qquad \text{and} \qquad B_{r_2}^{(d_2)}(x)
> \subseteq B_{r}^{(d_1)}(x).$$

I think that the two metrics are not strongly equivalent, so I go with the second approach. Let $r_1 = r$ and $y \in B_{r_1}^{(d_1)}(x)$. Then we have $$\left| \frac{1}{x} -
\frac{1}{y}\right| = \left| \frac{y - x}{xy}\right| \leq |x - y| < r.$$ Hence $y \in B_{r}^{(d_2)}(x)$. However, I am a bit clueless about how to show the second inclusion. **So my questions**:

- How do I show the second inclusion?
- Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that the two metrics are not strongly equivalent, and this tells you that $r_2$ should depend on $x$ and $r$. We can argue as follows to show that such $r_2$ exists.

Since $$\left|\frac1x-\frac1y\right|<r_2\iff \frac1x-r_2<\frac1y<\frac1x+r_2,$$ we choose $r_2<\frac1x$, and the condition above is equivalent to
$$\frac{x}{1+xr_2}<y<\frac{x}{1-xr_2}.$$
Thus,
$$-\frac{x^2r_2}{1+xr_2}<y-x<\frac{x^2r_2}{1-xr_2}.$$

Note that the absolute values of both sides tend to $0$ as $r_2$ tends to $0$. We can thus find some $r_2$ such that the absolute values are less than the given $r$.

(For example, choose $r_2$ such that $r_2<\frac{1}{2x}$ and $r_2<\frac{r}{2x^2}$.)

Comment: can we also argue that $\vert \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\vert = \vert \frac{x-y}{xy}\vert\lt \vert \frac{x-y}{x}\vert$ since $x,y\geq 1$. Then let $\delta\leq\epsilon x$ such that $x$ is fixed and $\vert x-y\vert\lt\delta\leq\epsilon x\Rightarrow \vert x-y\vert\lt\epsilon x\Rightarrow \vert \frac{x-y}{x}\vert\lt\epsilon\Rightarrow \vert \frac{x-y}{xy}\vert\lt\vert \frac{x-y}{x}\vert\lt\epsilon$?

Comment: @TheLastCipher You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $r_2$ such that:

$$r_2 < \frac{r}{x(x+r)}$$

note then that $r_2 < \frac1{x}$.

We have:

$$d_2(x,y) < r_2 \implies -r_2 < \frac1{y} - \frac1{x} < r_2 \implies \frac{x}{1+r_2x} < y < \frac{x}{1-r_2x}$$

From the first inequality and choice of $r_2$ we get:

$$y-x > \frac{x}{x+2r} (-r) > -r$$

From the second inequality we directly get $y-x < r$. Hence $d(x,y) < r$.

Comment: Now this should work fine. I don't know why I separated into two cases initially.

Answer (score 1):

$d_2(x,y) = d_1(f(x), f(y))$ for $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ which is continuous. Use this pointwise continuity to find the $r_1$ and $r_2$. Also $d_1(x,y) = d_2(f(x), f(y))$ as well,so it's symmetric.

Comment: Very nice. I also observed this. But then, I think it would be better to work with sequences, to use the continuity much more easily.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek Yes, you could use (maybe first prove) that two metrics are equivalent if they have exactly the same convergent sequences.

Comment: Hello Henne!! Does your answer hold also if instead of $M=[1,\infty)$ we had the set $(0,\infty)$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar I don't use the set anywhere, and $f$ is continuous and self-inverse on $(0,\infty)$ too. So yes, I'd say.

Comment: So also in the case of the set $X=(0,\infty)$ we can say that $d_2(x,y) = d_1(f(x), f(y))$ with $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, and this set is continuous on $X$, right? The function is self-inverse on $X$. I got stuck right now. Which are the conditions thathave to be satisfied so that the two metrics are topologically equivalent?

Comment: Do we just want that the function $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @MaryStar The continuity allows you to check the second condition the OP mentions, using $r_1,r_2$ etc.

Comment: So you mean that since $f$ is continuous we can find $r_1, r_2$ such that $$B_{r_1}^{(d_1)}(x)
\subseteq B_{r}^{(d_2)}(x) \qquad \text{and} \qquad B_{r_2}^{(d_2)}(x)
\subseteq B_{r}^{(d_1)}(x).$$ ?

Comment: Or since $f$ is continuous can we use then also the criterium with the sequences? Since the function is continuous, each convergent seuquence with $d_1$ converges also with metric $d_2$ with the same limit. Is this correct?

Comment: @MaryStar that works too, if you’ve covered that criterion in class.

Comment: So since the function is continuous do we just have to show that a sequence is convergent in the one metric?

Comment: @MaryStar it’s an iff statement so you do two (almost identical) directions.

Comment: I found somewehre the following: $$$$ 
Two metrices $d,d′$ on a set $X$ are topologically equivalent iff the map $(X,d)\rightarrow (X,d'), x\mapsto x$ is continuous and the map $(X,d')\rightarrow (X,d), x\mapsto x$ is continuous. 
From that we get that each convergent sequence in respect to $d$ converges also in respect to $d'$ with the same limit. 
$$$$ 
Or is this definition not correct?

Comment: If we can use that: We have that $d'(x,y)=d_1(f(x), f(y))$ with $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and the function $f$ is contiuous on $X$. 
We also have that  $d_1(x,y)=d'(f(x), f(y))$ with $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and the function $f$ is contiuous on $X$. 

Does it follow therefore that the two metrices are topologically equivalent?