# Show that the metrices are not strongly equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

We have the following metrices \begin{align*}&d_1(x,y)=|x-y| \\ &d_2(x,y)=\left |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right |=\frac{|x-y|}{|xy|}\end{align*} Iwant to show that these are not strongly equivalent.

To get an inequality with $d_1$ and $d_2$ it depends on the value of $|xy|$ if it is less or greater than $1$.

Does it follow from that that the two metrices are not strongly equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $d_1$ and $d_2$ are strongly equivalent if and only if there exist constants $k>0$ and $K>0$ such that
$$
kd_1(x,y)\le d_2(x,y)\le Kd_1(x,y)\qquad\text{for all $x,y$.}\tag{*}
$$
In particular (*) implies that
$$
\sup_{x,y} \frac{d_1(x,y)}{d_2(x,y)}
$$
must be finite.

Comment: I have a question... Why do we take the inequality in that way and not $kd_2(x,y)\le d_1(x,y)\le Kd_2(x,y)$ ? Or are these two inequalities equivalent ?

Comment: And also why do we get that $\sup_{x,y} \frac{d_1(x,y)}{d_2(x,y)}$ must be finite? If we consider the inequality of your answer and we divide by $d_1(x,y)$ then we get $$k\le \frac{d_2(x,y)}{d_1(x,y)}\le K$$ which means that $\frac{d_2(x,y)}{d_1(x,y)}=\frac{1}{|xy|}$ is bounded for all $x,y$, or have I understood that wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar To answer your first question: yes, the two versions of the inequalities are equivalent -- you should be able to prove this.

Comment: @MaryStar To answer your second question: Strong equivalence implies that both ratios must be bounded.  The fact that $1/|xy|$ is not bounded for all $x,y$ is the reason why these two metrics are not strongly equivalent.

Comment: So since for $x,y\rightarrow 0$ we get $\frac{1}{|xy|}\rightarrow \infty$ we get that the two metrices cannot be strongly equivalent, correct?

Comment: How can we check if these two are topologically equivalent?

Comment: @MaryStar Correct. To show they are topologically equivalent, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2391278/215011

Comment: Can we do the same as in these answer when we have $X=(0, \infty)$ instead of $M=[1,\infty)$ ?